# What are good ways to protect yourself against damaging your system when starting to learn coding/ a new language?

Tags: python, visual-studio

As the title says. I'll give some background as to why I ask this question. I have just started learning a bit of python, and embarrassingly I have re-named all the files in the anaconda folder by running a script I had written in the wrong folder due to misinterpreting the code I was using as an example. This is incredibly frustrating as you can imagine and seems to be quite an easy mistake for a beginner to make. I was wondering if there are any techniques to prevent this sort of thing happening when you're learning, other than being more careful?

Thanks for your advice.

Christian

Comment: Working step by step and not actually modifying files until you are 100% sure they are the files you want to modify is a good approach. Though that is basically "be more careful"

Comment: One way to not wreck your system might be using someone else's: afaik you can get a python VM at c9.io for free. so even if you break things, you can delete the old VM and get back to work with a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With low level languages like Assembly, it was much more common for beginners to make damaging mistakes but now adays, you cant do too much damage without really trying to do damage if that makes sense.

When it comes to scripts you don't entirely follow, you should look for things like

- Does it modify/read a file?
- Does it run any system commands like "rm -rf"
- Does it have any infinite loops or anything that seems strange?

Of course this is just a very simple list, there is no actual check list for "bad stuff".

In your case, it sounds like you just got unlucky. Don't look at it as a failure, look at it as you learned what the script can do.

You can also set up a Virtual Machine to use as a "sandbox" for your applications.

One last thing, since you are starting on this journey, it is important to make backups of your code/workspace and your important computer files. This is because you might want to go back to a previous version of your code.

Comment: Thankyou, this was helpful. I'm not familiar with virtual machines but it sounds exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I prefere setting up a virtual machine while coding 
"potential dangerous things" 
VM's also have the advantage of making snapshots before running the code that afterwards easily can be reset (e.g. for testing things multiple times)